# Hazelcast is calling loadAll() TWICE for the same key

Tags: distributed-computing, partitioning, hazelcast, in-memory-data-grid

As far as I'm aware, when using a MapLoader, Hazelcast calls `loadAllKeys()` once on the node which owns the partition which owns the map's name.

`loadAll(Collection<Long> keys)` is then only called on partitions which own a given key retrieved from `loadAllKeys()`. After this, the values are distributed as-needed around the cluster.

I'm performing a basic test with one node, one map and one record in my persistent store.

What I'm finding is `loadAllKeys()` is correctly called once, however, `loadAll(Collection<Long> keys)` is called twice. Why is this the case?

My implementation of `loadAll(Collection<Long> keys)` is as follows:

```
@Override
public synchronized Map<Long, MyCacheEntry> loadAll(Collection<Long> keys) {

    return myCacheRepository.loadMyCacheDataForKeys(keys)
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(MyCacheEntity::getId,
                                  entity -> gson.fromJson(entity.getValue(), MyCacheEntry.class)
                ));

}
```

This means that I am doing two lookups to my persistent storage instead of one. Seeing as though I have one record in my database I would expect `loadAll(Collection<Long> keys)` to only be called once.

What is happening here?

My crude, test Hazelcast/Spring configuration is as follows:

```
@Configuration
public class HazelcastConfiguration {

  private final MyMapStore myMapStore;

  @Inject
  HazelcastConfiguration(@Lazy MyMapStore myMapStore) {
    this.myMapStore = myMapStore;
  }

  @PreDestroy
  public void shutdown() {
    Hazelcast.shutdownAll();
  }

  @Bean
  public HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance() {

    Config config = new Config();
    config.getGroupConfig().setName("MyGroup");

    NetworkConfig networkConfig = config.getNetworkConfig();
    networkConfig.setPortAutoIncrement(false);

    JoinConfig joinConfig = networkConfig.getJoin();
    joinConfig.getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(false);
    joinConfig.getTcpIpConfig().setEnabled(true).setMembers(Collections.singletonList("127.0.0.1"));

    MapConfig mapConfig = new MapConfig("MyMap");
    mapConfig.setBackupCount(1);
    mapConfig.setAsyncBackupCount(1);
    mapConfig.setInMemoryFormat(InMemoryFormat.OBJECT);
    mapConfig.setTimeToLiveSeconds(0);

    EntryListenerConfig entryListenerConfig = new EntryListenerConfig();
    entryListenerConfig.setImplementation(new MyCacheEntryListener());
    mapConfig.addEntryListenerConfig(entryListenerConfig);

    MapStoreConfig mapStoreConfig = new MapStoreConfig();
    mapStoreConfig.setInitialLoadMode(MapStoreConfig.InitialLoadMode.EAGER);

    mapStoreConfig.setWriteDelaySeconds(1);
    mapStoreConfig.setImplementation(myMapStore);

    mapConfig.setMapStoreConfig(mapStoreConfig);

    config.addMapConfig(mapConfig);

    return Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
  }
}
```

Comment: I would need to see your config and a reproducer. 1 record is a special case. try with a 1000 and see what happens (also with 2 nodes later on.)

Comment: @tom.bujok I've updated to show my Hazelcast config. I also ran some tests with 5 records (instead of 1). loadAll() is hit twice for all five keys! My entry listener only registers that 5 items were added to the cache, however, from a performance perspective I do not want to be hitting my database twice as much than I need to.

Comment: Could you try without spring.I'm suspecting that the object creation is triggered twice somehow there.

Comment: You are correct. If I put the MapStore implementation in the HazelcastConfiguration class I no longer have the same issue. Why is this the case, though? Ideally I do not want to couple my MapStore implementation with my configuration. I am planning to use quite a few different map stores. What approach can I use instead, taking advantage of Spring's DI injection?

Comment: I've tried playing around with @SpringAware, but my MapStore ends up not having its dependencies injected - they end up being null. I define it using: mapStoreConfig.setClassName("com.my.cache.MyMapStore"); but this doesn't seem to inject them properly.

Comment: I  think there may be an issue that spring instantiates it again, so you end up with two map-stores, tough to say. You would need to debug object creation phase and the config class, that would tell you the truth.